# TCP SYN ACK manual construction?

Tags: c, tcp, syn

Im trying to manually create a TCP syn ack to a received ack packet. The spoofed synack however is being dropped by the source. The syn ack checksum shows as erroneous when observed from wireshark. below is the code i use for constructing the packet built with the help of  some online sources.

```
    /*
 * spoof.h
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 19, 2017
 *      Author: root
 */

#ifndef SPOOF_H_
#define SPOOF_H_

#endif /* SPOOF_H_ */

#ifndef _NETINET_TCP_H_
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#endif

#ifndef _NETINET_IP_H_
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#endif

#ifndef _LINUX_IF_ETHER_H
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#endif




struct in_addr dest_ip;
char *target;


unsigned short csum(unsigned short* ,int);
unsigned short compute_tcp_checksum(struct iphdr *, unsigned short *);
void compute_ip_checksum(struct iphdr* );
static unsigned short compute_checksum(unsigned short *, unsigned int );


char * syn_ack(char * pkbuff){
    char* datagram=(char*)malloc(1518);
    struct ethhdr *ethr = (struct ethhdr *)pkbuff;
    struct ethhdr *eths = (struct ethhdr *)datagram;

    struct iphdr *iphr = (struct iphdr *)(pkbuff+sizeof(struct ethhdr ));  //ip header of incoming packet
    struct iphdr *iphs = (struct iphdr *) (datagram + sizeof(struct ethhdr ));    // ip header of the spoofed packet

    struct tcphdr *tcphr = (struct tcphdr *)(pkbuff+sizeof(struct ethhdr )+sizeof(struct iphdr )); // TCP header of incomming packet
    struct tcphdr *tcphs =  (struct tcphdr *)(datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct ethhdr )); // ip header of spoofed packet



    memset(datagram,0,1518); /*zero out the buffer */

    // Fill in the IP header
    iphs->ihl =5;
    iphs->version = 4;
    iphs->tos = 0;
    iphs->tot_len = sizeof(struct iphdr )+sizeof(struct tcphdr );
    iphs->id = iphr->id;
    iphs->frag_off= 0x00;//htons(16384);
    iphs->ttl = 64;
    iphs->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iphs->check = 0;        //set to 0 before calculating checksum
    iphs->saddr = iphr->daddr;
    iphs->daddr = iphr->saddr;

    compute_ip_checksum(iphs);

    //TCP header
    tcphs->source = tcphr->dest;
    tcphs->dest = tcphr->source;
    tcphs->seq = htonl(1000000 + rand () % 90000);
    tcphs->ack_seq = htonl(ntohl(tcphr->seq) +1);
    tcphs->doff=sizeof(struct tcphdr)/4;
    tcphs->res1 = 0;
    tcphs->res2 = 0;
    tcphs->fin = 0;
    tcphs->syn = 1;
    tcphs->rst = 0;
    tcphs->psh = 0;
    tcphs->ack = 1;
    tcphs->urg =0;
    tcphs->window = htons(29200); // maximum allowed window size;
    tcphs->check  =0 ;
    tcphs->urg_ptr =0 ;





    tcphs->check = compute_tcp_checksum(iphs,(unsigned short*)tcphs);


    eths->h_dest[0] = ethr->h_source[0];
    eths->h_dest[1] = ethr->h_source[1];
    eths->h_dest[2] = ethr->h_source[2];
    eths->h_dest[3] = ethr->h_source[3];
    eths->h_dest[4] = ethr->h_source[4];
    eths->h_dest[5] = ethr->h_source[5];

    eths->h_source[0] = ethr->h_dest[0];
    eths->h_source[1] = ethr->h_dest[1];
    eths->h_source[2] = ethr->h_dest[2];
    eths->h_source[3] = ethr->h_dest[3];
    eths->h_source[4] = ethr->h_dest[4];
    eths->h_source[5] = ethr->h_dest[5];

    eths->h_proto = 8;

    return datagram;


}




//*************************CHECKSUM IMPLEMENTATION ************************************************




/* set tcp checksum: given IP header and tcp segment */

unsigned short compute_tcp_checksum(struct iphdr *pIph, unsigned short *ipPayload) {

    register unsigned long sum = 0;

    unsigned short tcpLen = ntohs(pIph->tot_len) - (pIph->ihl<<2);

    struct tcphdr *tcphdrp = (struct tcphdr*)(ipPayload);

    //add the pseudo header

    //the source ip

    sum += (pIph->saddr>>16)&0xFFFF;

    sum += (pIph->saddr)&0xFFFF;

    //the dest ip

    sum += (pIph->daddr>>16)&0xFFFF;

    sum += (pIph->daddr)&0xFFFF;

    //protocol and reserved: 6

    sum += htons(IPPROTO_TCP);

    //the length

    sum += htons(tcpLen);



    //add the IP payload

    //initialize checksum to 0

    tcphdrp->check = 0;

    while (tcpLen > 1) {

        sum += * ipPayload++;

        tcpLen -= 2;

    }

    //if any bytes left, pad the bytes and add

    if(tcpLen > 0) {

        //printf("+++++++++++padding, %dn", tcpLen);

        sum += ((*ipPayload)&htons(0xFF00));

    }

      //Fold 32-bit sum to 16 bits: add carrier to result

      while (sum>>16) {

          sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);

      }

      sum = ~sum;

    //set computation result

    //tcphdrp->check = (unsigned short)sum;
      return (unsigned short)sum;

}




//##############################IP CHECKSUM CALCULATION #####################################

/* set ip checksum of a given ip header*/

void compute_ip_checksum(struct iphdr* iphdrp){

  iphdrp->check = 0;

  iphdrp->check = compute_checksum((unsigned short*)iphdrp, iphdrp->ihl<<2);

}

/* Compute checksum for count bytes starting at addr, using one's complement of one's complement sum*/

static unsigned short compute_checksum(unsigned short *addr, unsigned int count) {

  register unsigned long sum = 0;

  while (count > 1) {

    sum += * addr++;

    count -= 2;

  }

  //if any bytes left, pad the bytes and add

  if(count > 0) {

    sum += ((*addr)&htons(0xFF00));

  }

  //Fold sum to 16 bits: add carrier to result

  while (sum>>16) {

      sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);

  }

  //one's complement

  sum = ~sum;

  return ((unsigned short)sum);

}
```

what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: I believe you are going to have to fully emulate the TCP three-way handshake to get what you want since a SYNACK is only valid in response to a SYN.

Comment: Which is why it's going to be rejected anyway, even when you get the checksum right.